# Inspecting std::any in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

`std:::any e = 1.0f;`

And this is what I get in VS watch:

[image: VS Watch]

Is there a way to get the value and the type?

If I use `std::any_cast<float>(e)` it works, but what If I don't know the type.

If I use any other <> invalid type in std::any_cast I guess that the debugger crashes. It detaches from my app and then I get an invalid type message in the watch window.

Comment: I guess you don't. Yet another reason to avoid `std::any`. BTW `(float)1.0f` is completely redundant.

Comment: Don't know if the debugger allows it, but `e.type().name()` should give you some string describing the type in some form.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the type, you already see this in the `type` field (notice the `float` before the `RTTI Type Descriptor`.
Unfortunately, getting the actual value in the debugger is not really possible at the moment. See [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/make-stdany-natvis-extensions-more-useful/1380848) feature request on the developer community.

Note that there is a somewhat hacky workaround posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66924250/3740047) which edits the default natvis file provided with Visual Studio and requires you to add additional C++ code to your project. Moreover, in that C++ code you need to manually enumerate all the possible values that `std::any` might take (see the `AnyCasterService` constructor).